# Is it possible to define string expressions in array as key in object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are many sms sending service providers and all of these services have different parameter names. I do not know which company is using which web service provider. If I request the parameters to be requested from the user during the soap request, is it possible to define these parameters as object keys?

For example:

First user request parameters  : [companyName ,msgBody,recipients],

Another user request parameters: [id,msgText,numbers,channelCode],

If we have defined this array to the function parameter that will send the sms request.

And I want to create Object for Soap Body.

Result for First user : obj={companyName:'ASDDASD',msgBody:'Hello',recipients:'0264344534'}

Result for Another user : obj ={id:21,msgText:'hi,numbers:54564234,channelCode:1}

Note: obj values ​​are written randomly

Comment: Is the order of values in the array always the same?

Comment: Yes, that wil be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets to reference property names: `obj['propname']`
If you want to use a variable for the key name in an object literal, you can use [ES2015 computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Syntax): `{ [keyname]: 'value' }`

```js
keys1 = ['companyName', 'msgBody','recipients']
vals1 = [1, 2, 3]

keys2 = ['id','msgText','numbers','channelCode']

const obj1 = {}, obj2 = {}
keys1.forEach((key,i) => obj1[key]=vals1[i])
keys2.forEach(key => obj2[key]=key+'value')

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1), JSON.stringify(obj2))

console.log(JSON.stringify(
{
 [keys1[0]]: 'value'
}
))
```

Comment: keys2.forEach(key => obj2[key] = \`${key}value\`)

Answer (score 0):

You would need a function like this?
Assuming the parameters are strings (['a','b'], not [a,b]) and the objects are an array of javascript objects.

```js
/* function projectObjects
@params: an array of string parameters
@objects: an array of objects with these parameters as properties
Projects the objects on the parameter list and returns an array of objects with all and only params as properties */
function projectObjects(params,objects) {

   let projectOne = function(o) {
       let result = {};
       params.forEach(
          (p) => {
             // check the behaviour when o[p] is undefined
             result[p] = o[p];
          }
       )
       return result;
   }
   
   results = objects.map(projectOne);
   return results;

}

console.log(projectObjects(['roses'],[{'roses':1,'violets':2},{'roses':3,'begonias':22},{'daisies':0}]));
```